# Javascript - Open a given URL in a new tab by clicking a button

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a button that redirects to a given URL and opens in a new tab. How can this be done?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Use this:

```
<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com/page')" />
```

Worked for me and it will open an actual new 'popup' window rather than a new full browser or tab. You can also add variables to it to stop it from showing specific browser traits as follows:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=600,left=10,top=10,,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no'); return false;"
```

Comment: @wong2 Might want to change answer to this one. The one currently selected is far to wordy to be efficient.

Answer (score 122):

In javascript you can do:

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Answer (score 45):

Adding target="_blank" should do it:

```
<a id="myLink" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

Comment: I see, sorry I've missed that. Well, you could style the link to look and feel like a button. If you're using jQuery UI just use [button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) to do so.

Comment: Excellent solution for the vast majority of us who merely dabble in web design!  Thank you!

Comment: +1 because you gave a good solution to those looking for a simple "open link in new tab" answer, if they aren't using a button.

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: +1, if something opens a page in new tab, it is logically a link, so `<a>` tag is appropriate. Styles should be used to make it look like a button.

Comment: There are a lot of VALID reasons on why you have to use a `<button>` for link and can't replace it with `<a>`. e.g. you're using a HTML template and the author styled social icons based on `<button>` element like `button.social-icon{ width:... }`. It's not a good idea to edit the author styles because the 'update' process will become a pain in your _somewhere..._

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27):

You can forget about using JavaScript because the browser controls whether or not it opens in a new tab. Your best option is to do something like the following instead:

```
<form action="http://www.yoursite.com/dosomething" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input name="dynamicParam1" type="text"/>
    <input name="dynamicParam2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This will always open in a new tab regardless of which browser a client uses due to the `target="_blank"` attribute.

If all you need is to redirect with no dynamic parameters you can use a link with the `target="_blank"` attribute as Tim Büthe suggests.

Comment: Works as required (tested on chrome, firefox, IE10) :)

Answer (score 16):

My preferred method has the advantage of no JavaScript embedded in your markup:

**CSS**

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Link-button"></a>
```

Comment: Well, I guess I have a new preferred method.

Comment: Prefer the `a input[type=button]` CSS selector instead of just `a`

Answer (score 12):

Use `window.open` instead of `window.location` to open a new window or tab (depending on browser settings).

Your fiddle does not work because there is no `button` element to select. Try `input[type=button]` or give the button an `id` and use `#buttonId`.

Answer (score 7):

> Open in new tab using javascript

```
 <button onclick="window.open('https://www.our-url.com')" id="myButton" 
 class="btn request-callback" >Explore More  </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used target="_blank" under form tag and it worked fine with FF and Chrome where it opens in a new tag but with IE it opens in a new window.

Comment: Whether a tab or window opens is determined by the user's browser options.  I don't know about IE, but in most browsers the webpage cannot choose whether the link opens in a tab or a window, but the user can configure it.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<a id="link" href="www.gmail.com" target="_blank" >gmail</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **React** or **Javascript** we can do:

```js
<button onClick={() => window.open(url, "_blank")}> content </button>
```

To use an **Anchor** tag:

```js
<a href="url" target="_blank" > content </a>
```

Comment: You can also replace the button with a div or any other tag.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is reading this post in 2024, you can try this:

```
    // Set the contract button to open the contract in a new tab
    mybutton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); //to avoid changes the current page url
        window.open(myurl, '_blank');//the behavior is defined by the browser and user options
        return false;//It prevents the default action associated with the event
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use button as anchor tag

```html
<button
     target="_blank"
     rel="noreferrer"
     as="a"
     href="https://example.com"
   >
   Open
   </button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Button_name" onclick="window.open('LINKADDRESS')"/>
```

Answer (score -6):

```
<BUTTON NAME='my_button' VALUE=sequence_no TYPE='SUBMIT' style="background-color:transparent ; border:none; color:blue;" onclick="this.form.target='_blank';return true;"><u>open new page</u></BUTTON>
```

This button will look like a URL and can be opened in a new tab.

Comment: you need to add "form"

Comment: It's not a good idea (semantically speaking) to have a button to behave like a link. Instead, use the `a` tag.

Answer (score -7):

You can't. This behaviour is only available for plugins and can only be configured by the user.

Answer (score -7):

USE this code

```
function openBackWindow(url,popName){
        var popupWindow = window.open(url,popName,'scrollbars=1,height=650,width=1050');
          if($.browser.msie){
            popupWindow.blur();
            window.focus();
        }else{
           blurPopunder();
        }
      };

    function blurPopunder() {
            var winBlankPopup = window.open("about:blank");
            if (winBlankPopup) {
                winBlankPopup.focus();
                winBlankPopup.close()
            }
    };
```

IT works fine in Mozilla,IE and chrome on and less than 22 version; but doesn't work in Opera and Safari.

Comment: This is not the best answer! Solid -1.

Comment: USe this code is not really an answer and you have no motivation behind it.