# Open URL in new window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, new-window

I'm making a "share button" to share the current page. I would like to take the current page URL and open it in a new window. I have the current URL part working, but can't seem to get the next part working.

I'm struggling with the syntax. I would like to specify the new window size to `width=520, height=570`.

Something like:

```
<a target="_blank"
   href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?mini=true&amp;url=[sub]" 
   onclick="this.href = this.href.replace('[sub]',window.location)">
    LinkedIn
</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Open a given URL in a new tab by clicking a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303964/javascript-open-a-given-url-in-a-new-tab-by-clicking-a-button)

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Use `window.open()`:

```
<a onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">
  Share Page
</a>
```

This will create a link titled `Share Page` which opens the current url in a new window with a height of 570 and width of 520.

Comment: how to set window's height and width to zero, if i set to zero it is showing full screen

Comment: how do we open it as a normal window rather than pop - up window? because unable to open new tab

Comment: @AkshathaSrinivas the minimum height is 100

Comment: Can I send some parameters to these page also how can I use them to new window?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan If you want it to open in a new tab in your browser then use: window.open("https://www.w3schools.com"). If you want to open it in the same tab then : window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", '_self');

Answer (score 86):

Just use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) function? The third parameter lets you specify window size.

#### Example

```
var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
var URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?mini=true&amp;url=" + location.href;
var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
```

Comment: shiplu.mokadd.im That seems to be what I need but I am not sure where it goes.

Comment: @MarkMitchell If you don't care about coding standards - into the `onclick` attribute. A slightly better option is to create a function that you call from the `onclick`. Using `getElementById` and `addEventListener` is cleaner still. Using jQuery to get a shorter syntax (and some other features + tons of plugins) is very popular as well.

Comment: How is that the 4th parameter? It looks like the 3rd to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CoderDennis Nice catch. Fixed it.

Comment: hi how can I trigger the window close event?

Comment: @DilakshanSooriyanathan you can close the opened window using the variable that you gave to the new window. The code above would use `win.close()`.

Answer (score 15):

Don't confuse, if you won't give any strWindowFeatures then it will open in a new tab.

```
window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drishya');
```

Comment: I don't think that's true. At least in the Linux Chrome I'm using, the same `window.open(url, '_blank')` seems to decide whether to open a new window or a new tab based on whether I hold down the shift or control key, respectively, with my click.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's too late, but,

Steps for opening a link in a new tab:

1. Create an `a` element
2. Set the href ( `"https://example.com"` )
3. Set `target` to `"_blank"`
4. Click on the link

**Code**:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var link = document.createElement("a")
  link.href = "https://example.com"
  link.target = "_blank"
  link.click()
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer around. Does not get caught to the popup blocking.

Comment: Beautiful, works like a complete charm. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: OP asking to open in a new window not in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

The following is JavaScript to be used in a function:
Note, I have 1's and 0's instead of yes and no.

```
var theTop=((screen.height/2)-(theHeight/2))/2;
var theLeft=(screen.width/2)-(theWidth/2);
var features = 'height=600,width=800,top='+theTop+',left='+theLeft+',toolbar=1,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,menubar=1,Scrollbars=1,Resizable=1';

window.open(in_uri, WindowName, features);
```