# How to open a link in new window with Javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to open a link in a new window using Javascript or HTML. Here is what I have tried which I I have found NOT to work:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" title="Google" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

I use Mozilla Firefox. Is this possible? I have looked at a lot of Stack Overflow questions, none of them seem to work.

Comment: I said new "window", not "tab". :)

Comment: Sorry, use window.open

Comment: Please describe *how* your attempts don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox has an explicit option to open a new tab when the page demands a new window. I don't think that you can override this.

Comment: This is correct. To open a link in a new window using Firefox, you must go to Tools, then click Options. Now all you have to do is un-check the box labeled "Open new tabs in a new window instead", then hit OK.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't find an answer to this question on SO?

How about here? [Open URL in new window with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

As explained in that post, try window.open()

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Link</a>
```

Comment: It is for some replacing the page I click the link on with the one it is supposed to open in a new window... Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: This link also seems to address your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab  According this post, a width and height parameter is necessary in firefox to indicate a new window.

Comment: I just noticed that link is from 2009... worth noting.

Comment: You say it did not work.  I have 2 questions. 1) What behavior are you getting? 2) What version of firefox are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

**HTML :**

**Using Button**

```
<button id="hoo">Click me</button>
```

**Using link**

```
<a href="#" id="hoo">Click Me</a>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
hoo.onclick = function ShowWindow() { 
    window.open("http://www.google.com/", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=600,left=100,top=30,resizable=Yes,scrollbars=Yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=No');
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mLT6/5/)

Comment: For some reason I cannot even get the JavaScript to run using that code..

Comment: Isn't it working properly?? I mean i tried it and the url gets opened in a new window. isn't it what you want!!