# How do I open Javascript link in new tab

Tags: javascript

In an website I'm working in wich I include a script from booking.com so that visitors can check the availability of a hotel directly. But when the visitor clicks on the button "check availability" he goes to a new website (of booking.com). But I want the link to open in a new tab/windows and not in the same one as the current website (the one I'm creating).

The script I'm using is just a regular (script type="text/javascript" src="heregoesthelink")(/script) include. (Sorry about the () but otherwise it doesn't show the text here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi, you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript this link..

Comment: In the link above they try to open a link/button in a new tab/windows. What I'm trying to do is open javascript src that I can't change or the script isn't working.

I tried for example adding window.open('...') to the script, but then it doesn't show the original script that's included.