# Append url from text box and open new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

An onclick function is supposed to fire up a new window with a string and the textbox value appended to the url, but it doesn't seem to work. (The string will populate another textbox in the new window. This however, functions properly.)

When I use window.location it works but I don't want the page to open in the same window.

I'm very new to Javascript, thank you for your help.

Javascript

```
function changeLocation(){
var textboxpw = document.getElementById("key");
window.open{'http://website.com?secret="+textboxpw.value), '_blank';}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="key" id="key" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="changeLocation(); return false;" />
```

Comment: check this [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: what is the `textboxpw` varialbe contain??

Comment: another one [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript) ,hopefully it can help you

Comment: Why are you using curly brackets to enclose the arguments to the `window.open()` function? Is that intentional? Are you doing that in your original code?

Comment: use `url = encodeURIComponent('http://website.com?secret="+textboxpw.value');` for the url

Answer (score 5):

```
function changeLocation(){
    var textboxpw = document.getElementById("key");
    window.open('http://website.com?secret='+encodeURIComponent(textboxpw.value), '_blank');
}
```

Comment: good use of `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: I tried this, didn't open a window.

Comment: What happens when you call `changeLocation`?

Answer (score 1):

The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI component.

This function encodes special characters.

In addition, it encodes the following characters:

> , / ? : @ & = + $ #

**Example:**

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

**output:**

http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab

The open() method opens a new browser window.

> syntax: window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

**If your code block works fine except new window then try:**

```
function changeLocation(){
    textboxpw = document.getElementById("key");
    url = encodeURIComponent('http://website.com?secret='+textboxpw.value);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not launch a new window.

Comment: did you see `If your code block works fine except new window then try` in my answer?? I didn't change anything in your code, just add a function.