# How to trigger a new window to be opened from a button click in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dom-events

I have a button and on click of that button a new window should be opened with a new provided URL.
For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-help"(click)="helpWindow($event)" type="submit"></button>
```

How do I handle this even at backend in the typescript file? I will get the URL from REST API and I want to open a new window with that link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
helpWindow(event) {
  window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132265/217408

Comment: Is there an angular way to construct the URL if I need to attach query params?

Comment: No, just use what plain JS/TS and browser API provide

Comment: Thanks! I needed to use it in `<button icon-only (click)="loadURLinNewTab(app.url)">`. onclick is forbidden due to security.