# Opening New Windows in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, new-window

At my workplace, there is a website we regularly visit to obtain some information.  Upon clicking a link in the page, a new window opens and displays the information.  This currently works fine in IE8+, but the link is dead in chrome.  I've checked and after researching, I believe that chrome is blocking from a new window to open due to security measures.  I get no warnings or pop ups, JavaScript is enabled, pop up is allowed for all sites, so now I'm a bit stuck.  Is there a built in command to access the chrome features and enable to open new windows?  We are using chrome mostly and would like to resolve on this browser.  The onclick script looks like this:

`onclick="javascript:OpenW('ViewInvoiceEstimate.asp?EIID=2984252&EI=I&Tabname=OPEN')`

When I attached the link section of the script as the suffix to the web address, the content shows up fine from the same web browser.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)?

Comment: I don't have access to the web script and to modify them, sadly.  It is my client's web page, and I'm trying to figure out a workaround from my end, if there is any.

Comment: chrome may not be supporting that openW function anymore. You may see an error in JavaScript console when you click the link

Comment: Yes that's right.  I get Uncaught TypeError: window.showModalDialog is not a function at OpenW (I547) and at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (I781)