# Use JS to open window in place of current browser window and then close it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Ok, I know that you cant close a window using JS unless your JS script also opened that window. So, is it possible to open a new window in place of the current window & then close it?

I have a button that onclick send some value to my DB once they hit ok on the popup, the window should close.

Any specific way this can be done?

Comment: Just don't use a popup window, many browsers block those by default and also the browser might choose how it's opened (it may also open a new tab instead of a real window).

Comment: so how do I get that behaviour of sending the user entry, have them press ok on an alert and then the page/tab close? or is that not doable?

Comment: Show modal dialog (popular frameworks offer these) and populate it how you want to.  The user interacts (changes things then presses a button) and you use Ajax to post the data to your server, then close the modal dialog - still in the same browser and on the original page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open URL in new window with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Comment: I can open the window fine, it's just not closing. That question is about how to open, mine is more how to close.

Comment: Maybe this [How can I close a browser window ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi) might help

Comment: @Sorix That question is about closing a window without the popup you get when you weren't the opener.  It's not relevant here as the OP is opening the window from their own script.

Comment: @Archer window.close() should work in this case. I agree that it is not the same question but if the answer is the same, maybe there is no need to open a new question for every similar problem. On the other hand, if window.close() is not working, the question might need further detailing.

Comment: @Sorix yes, `window.close()` is exactly what the OP needs, but the question you linked covers a different topic.  It's misleading if all that's needed is closing a window, and will just confuse the issue.

Comment: @marcel can you not downvote this? It's not a duplicate.

Comment: I’m  not the one who downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you can close a window if it was opened by a script.  If your 2nd window has a button in it like this...

```
<button id="closeWindow">click me to close this window</button>
```

Then you can attach this Javascript...

```
document.querySelector("#closeWindow").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.close();
});
```

Add that script into the page that you show in the new window and it will close it when you click the button.

However, as I said in my comment above, I'd really recommend using a modal dialog instead, like you see with the likes of Bootstrap etc..  They're much nicer, very user friendly and easier to work with.