# Pop-out Window without search-bar or tabs

Tags: html

Very simple question:

I'm trying to re-make this type of pop-out window for my own website, but I don't know how its called/made.

This window type...

[image]
I've tried A-Tag targets like: `target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename"`.. But non of them is the correct one. Does anyone know how this window type is called/made?

Comment: You're looking for the JavaScript command `window.open`. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Comment: I've tried that. But that doesn't open that certain pop-out window. ``window.open``  just opens a new, normal window.

Comment: There is an option called `menubar` which allows you to disable the menu.  That might be what you're looking for.  I posted an answer with the full code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript command `window.open` should be what you're looking for.  You can open a window with specific settings, which includes disabling the menu bar with the `menubar=no` option.

Example:

```html
<a href="#" onclick='window.open("https://stackoverflow.com", "_blank", "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,menubar=no")'>Click me!</a>
```