# How do we open more than one javascript: url window with window.open?

Tags: javascript

If you run the following in Chrome console multiple times, it will update the same window over and over:

```
var win = window.open(`javascript:document.write(' <h1> Hello!!! </h1> ')`, 'test')
```

But how do we make it open a new window?

Comment: Use `"_blank"`: `var win = window.open("javascript:document.write(' <h1> Hello!!! </h1> ')", '_blank')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open URL in new window with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use _blank property**

like this :

```
var win = window.open(`javascript:document.write(' <h1> Hello!!! </h1> ')`, '_blank')
```

Comment: So obscure, thanks! It wasn't obvious because the first call opens a new window, so one may think that another call would also open another window.