# Opening Webpages in new tab using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We Know That we can redirect to web pages using location.href or location.replace but I wanted to ask that can We open a new webpage in a new tab using JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open URL in new window with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
window.open(url, '_blank')
```

where url is the link you want to open

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `window.open(url)`

for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open