# Submit button Javascript to open a URL entered into a text field

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

I have a PDF form that users will enter a link to a SharePoint folder or file. I want to have a button next to the link (text field) that when pressed will open a web browser to the URL that was entered. I've been toying with Javascript codes but can't find a code that works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer, see the [Help page, How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also refer to [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open URL in new window with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)