# error with webbrowser module while deploying my app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, streamlit

I was trying to deploy my web app on Heroku and I was using the `webbrowser` module to open a link when a button is clicked but the deployment failed with this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webbrowser (from -r/tmp/build_1a0f381f625ed056f039e4b30415d590/requirements.txt (line 7)) 
(from versions: none)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for webbrowser (from -r /tmp/build_1a0f381f625ed056f039e4b30415d590/requirements.txt (line 7))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is the `requirements.txt` file:

```
joblib>=0.14.0
numpy>=1.9.2
matplotlib>=1.4.3
pandas>=0.19
streamlit
scikit-learn==0.22.1
webbrowser
```

And here is how I use `webbrowser`:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('URL')
```

When I deployed the app without mentioning `webbrowser` in the `requirements.txt` file the app was deployed successfully but the feature of opening the URL when the button is clicked was not working.

Comment: How do you use `webbrowser` in your code? What do you expect to happen on Heroku? Normally, this [would run an actual web browser](https://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser), but popping a window up on some server in some AWS data centre doesn't make much sense. (Note that `webbrowser` is a built-in module—you don't need to install it via `requirements.txt`. That might fix your build error, but the previous question remains.)

Comment: `import webbrowser`
`webbrowser.open('URL')`    this is how I was using web-browser to open the URL.i created a button and when it is clicked it is supposed to open the URL. when I didn't mention the web-browser module in `requirements.txt` the feature was not working.

Answer (score 1):

[The `webbrowser` module is part of Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser). You don't need to (and *can't*) install it via `pip`, so it doesn't belong in your `requirements.txt`. Take it back out.

Now that your deployment is working, we need to fix the real problem: you can't open a browser with `webbrowser` on Heroku. Python code runs on the *server*, not the client. If this does anything it will open a browser on a machine somewhere in an AWS data centre, not on the client machine.

I'm not sure how you've connected your button to the back-end, but [JavaScript can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) [open windows on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132265/354577).

Be *careful* doing this, as pop-ups have a very bad reputation and users generally don't like them. Furthermore, many browsers have protection against this now; your users will probably have to approve the pop-up. I *strongly* recommend finding another solution that doesn't involve creating new browser windows.