# how can I open mutliple urls in flask app

Tags: python, flask

I want to open multiple urls in separate tabs in my flask app

using following code only first url gets opened.

```
 @app.route('/get_spot', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def spot():
    urls =['https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/puzzles/','https://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/home.php','https://web.whatsapp.com/']
    
    for url in urls:
        return redirect(url)
```

I have tried using selenium webdriver,
which is very slow, and creates new window on each call.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank");'.format(url))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in JavaScript with the `window.open` function, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132265/672833

You could create a loop in JavaScript and open one will window after another.

The JavaScript needs to be called/triggered in a template file.