# How to open popup in JavaScript? (NOT window.open)

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, window.open

This is kind of a dumb question, but what is the command to open a popup window in JS? I know that window.open works, but on chrome, it shows the tabs, which I have seen in popups  not existing. ***It should just show the address at the top.*** Hopefully I expressed this question correctly.

## EDIT:

**In the third parameter of window.open, you can specify "popup=true".**

Comment: window.open(
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "mozillaWindow",
  "popup,left=100,top=100,width=320,height=320"
);

It will open popup window with just url

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Thank you! This was the exact answer I was looking for!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open URL in new window with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default behavior is to open in a new tab. However, using the third parameter `windowFeatures` in the `window.open(...);` function will allow you to set parameters to force the request to open in a new popup with the minimal UI elements that you're requesting. For example:

```
window.open("{url}", "_blank", "popup=yes");
```

**Reference Documentation:** [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: I've been using window.open for over 2 years, yet I've never seen or used this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the `popup` option in the `windowsFeatures` (third) parameter should produce the result you want.

```
window.open('', '', 'popup=true')
```

[Learn more about `window.open` from MDN, here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Hope this helps.