# Is there a way to click an image then it'll open the link in a new tab without using anchor tags, purely JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

Help me pleaz

```
let discordLogo = document.createElement("img");
discordLogo.setAttribute(
  "src",
  "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1079211646746099792/1079217653916377148/discord.png?width=470&height=470"
);
discordLogo.style.width = "40px";
discordLogo.style.height = "40px";
discordLogo.style.position = "absolute";
discordLogo.style.top = "14px";
discordLogo.setAttribute("id", "discordInv");
discordLogo.style.right = "75px";
main.appendChild(discordLogo);

document.querySelector("#discordInv").addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.location.href = ("https://discord.gg/52BTDY"); // THIS WORKS BUT IT WON'T TARGET "_BLANK" OR WHATEVER PLEASE HELP
});
```

was expecting it to work and open the discord invite in another tab

Comment: Search about `window.open`

Comment: Please search before asking questions [Open URL in new window with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Comment: The most normal question I’ve seen all day.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
window.open("https://discord.gg/52BTDY");
```

instead of

```
window.location.href = ("https://discord.gg/52BTDY");
```

This opens  your link in a new tab, and is similar to the

```
target = "_blank"
```

property in CSS.