# Open new tabs with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to know, how can I open a link in a new tab/window with Angular. I have a regular website and when user click in a button "already registered", I need to open a new tab with a login page.

Should I use $location to map the path? Best practices?

Answer (score 32):

You can use angular's [window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window) service. To open 'url' in a new tab,

```
$window.open('url');
```

Comment: @user1883793: (Not sure but) Seems like in your browser settings, you have set new pages to open in new window.

Comment: `$window.open('url', '_blank');` will open it in new tab. your snippet opens a new window

Comment: its working fine in chrome and firefox but in IE user get loggedout and redirected to login page.is there some work around to solve the issue for IE

Comment: Everything I've read says that it's dependent upon the browsers' settings whether it will open a new window or a new tab if you include `, '_blank'`. Unfortunately, each browser behaves differently, especially when manually configured. @user1883793 @NituBansai

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open a new tab I would suggest having your [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) have a '/login' route and simply have your button link to '/login', however, keep in mind you'll be reloading the entire app if you wish to keep the login page within the application when opening a new tab.

You could combine it with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303964/open-an-url-in-a-new-tab-when-click-a-button) to open a small login window separate of the app as well, and listen for the window to close and handle the response.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the button type is not of type "submit" also or it won't work at all.