# input onclick new tab

Tags: html, onclick

```
<form name="test">
<select name="choose" style="width:300px;">
<option selected="">Select option</option>
<option value="http://url.com">Test</option>
</select>
<input onclick="location=document.test.choose.options[document.test.choose.selectedIndex].value;" value="Take me there!" type="button"></p>
</form>
```

Im using the following to make a dropdown list and was just wondering how i would make selected open in a new tab and not in its own window

Works fine as it is just need it to open in a new tab.

*** Edit ***

This worked as needed thanks

```
<input onClick="window.open(document.test.choose.options[document.test.choose.selectedIndex].value);" value="Take me there!" type="button">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: target="_blank" opens pages in tabs rather than new windows

Comment: with html I use target="_blank" not sure how to apply it in your situation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try window.open

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');
```

### update

live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/tzp4H/

Comment: that will open in a new window, not a new tab

Answer (score 3):

```
function open_in_new_tab(url )
{
  var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Call that function when you want to open a link in a new tab. Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303964/open-an-url-in-a-new-tab-when-click-a-button)

Comment: Duplicate question, duplicate (and incorrect) answer. This is not possible if the browser, let's say, IE, has [_Tabbed Browsing_](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-tabbed-browsing-in-internet-explorer-7/) disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your updated answer to your original post:

Adding `,'_blank'` after the `.value` like so:

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.open(document.test.choose.options[document.test.choose.selectedIndex].value,'_blank');>
```

Actually opens in a new tab instead of an entirely new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing advanced or similar. You just need to add _blank as the following example demonstrate.

```
  <a href="someLink.html" target="_blank">
      <button>Visit my Github</button>
  </a>
```