# Javascript - Open an URL in a new tab by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
 {
     text: 'Berkas',
     align: 'center',
     cell: {

         xtype: 'button',
         dataIndex: 'file_kp_prodi_mhs',
         text: 'View',
         handler: function(button, e) {
             window.open(file_kp_prodi_mhs);
         },

     }
 }
```

Comment: Hello, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303964/javascript-open-a-given-url-in-a-new-tab-by-clicking-a-button

Comment: window.open(url, "_blank");

Comment: @MadhuMagar 121/5000
I store url in database, its value is in index data. how to get to the link stored in the index data?

Comment: @spstrademark i have tried, but still not call the link i stored in DataIndex

Comment: @ShellaEldwina what is the structure of index data?

Comment: @MadhuMagar i stored the link in dataIndex

Comment: @ShellaEldwina Can you show dataindex? I mean dataindex object structure.

Comment: @MadhuMagar    {name: 'file_kp_prodi_mhs', type: 'string'}.   in the database, the file_pk_prodi contains the link. I want the button when clicked, it opens the saved link address

Answer (score 1):

Try this(change out vg.no with what you want):

```
<div href="https://www.vg.no" onclick="openInNewTab('https://www.vg.no')">Something To Click On</div>
    <script>
        function openInNewTab(url) {
            var win = window.open(url);
        win.focus();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get value from record like:

```
 {
     text: 'Berkas',
     align: 'center',
     cell: {
         xtype: 'button',
         dataIndex: 'file_kp_prodi_mhs',
         text: 'View',
         handler: function(button, e) {
             window.open(e.record.get(button.dataIndex));
         },
     }
 }
```